# Left joining in R between two timestamps

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, tidyverse

My goal is to perform a left join on `intervals` where the `bike_id` matches and the `created_at` timestamp in `records` is BETWEEN `start` and `end` in the `intervals` table

```
> class(records)
[1] "data.table" "data.frame"
> class(intervals)
[1] "data.table" "data.frame"

> records
  bike_id          created_at         resolved_at
1   28780 2019-05-03 08:29:18 2019-05-03 08:35:37
2   28780 2019-05-03 21:05:28 2019-05-03 21:07:28
3   28780 2019-05-04 21:13:39 2019-05-04 21:15:40
4   28780 2019-05-07 17:24:20 2019-05-07 17:26:39
5   28780 2019-05-08 11:34:32 2019-05-08 12:16:44
6   28780 2019-05-08 23:38:39 2019-05-08 23:40:36


> intervals
   bike_id               start                 end id
1:   28780 2019-05-03 04:44:45 2019-05-03 16:58:56  1
2:   28780 2019-05-04 07:07:39 2019-05-04 14:48:29  2
3:   28780 2019-05-07 23:28:32 2019-05-08 12:56:24  3
4:   28780 2019-05-10 06:06:21 2019-05-10 13:12:08  4
5:   28780 2019-05-12 05:21:24 2019-05-12 11:35:52  5
6:   28780 2019-05-13 08:44:54 2019-05-13 12:28:31  6
```

In this case, the output would look like

```
> output
  bike_id          created_at         resolved_at   id
1   28780 2019-05-03 08:29:18 2019-05-03 08:35:37    1
2   28780 2019-05-03 21:05:28 2019-05-03 21:07:28  NULL   
3   28780 2019-05-04 21:13:39 2019-05-04 21:15:40  NULL
4   28780 2019-05-07 17:24:20 2019-05-07 17:26:39  NULL
5   28780 2019-05-08 11:34:32 2019-05-08 12:16:44  NULL
6   28780 2019-05-08 23:38:39 2019-05-08 23:40:36  NULL
```

I have tried using the solution [posted here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/tidy-way-to-range-join-tables-on-an-interval-of-dates/7881) using `tidyverse` but this causes R to run out of memory (although the amount of record in both tables are only about 100K)

```
library('fuzzyjoin')

fuzzy_left_join(
 records, intervals,
  by = c(
    "bike_id" = "bike_id",
    "created_at" = "start",
    "created_at" = "end"
    ),
  match_fun = list(`==`, `>=`, `<=`)
  ) %>%
  select(id, bike_id = bike_id.x, created_at, start, end)
```

this throws the error: `Error: vector memory exhausted (limit reached?)`

Is there an alternative method with rolling join in `data.table` or even in base R using `merge()` ? What is a good method to join two dataframes by id and where a timestamp is between two others n the join table?

Here is the data

```
dput(intervals)
structure(list(bike_id = c(28780L, 28780L, 28780L, 28780L, 28780L, 
28780L), start = structure(c(1556858685, 1556953659, 1557271712, 
1557468381, 1557638484, 1557737094), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), tzone = "UTC"), end = structure(c(1556902736, 1556981309, 
1557320184, 1557493928, 1557660952, 1557750511), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x1030056e0>)

dput(records)
structure(list(bike_id = c(28780L, 28780L, 28780L, 28780L, 28780L, 
28780L), created_at = structure(c(1556872158.796, 1556917528.845, 
1557004419.928, 1557249860.939, 1557315272.396, 1557358719.333
), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), resolved_at = structure(c(1556872537.867, 
1556917648.118, 1557004540.056, 1557249999.892, 1557317804.183, 
1557358836.202), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC")), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: You can try nonequi join in `data.table` `setDT(records)[intervals, on = .(bike_id, created_at >= start, created_at <= end)]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know OP asked for a `tidyverse` or `data.table` solution, but SQL seems to be the perfect tool for this:

```
library(sqldf)

sqldf("select a.*, b.id 
        from records as a
        left join intervals as b
          on a.bike_id = b.bike_id and
            a.created_at >= b.start and
            a.created_at <= b.end")
```

or use `between` for an alternate syntax:

```
sqldf("select a.*, b.id 
        from records as a
        left join intervals as b
          on a.bike_id = b.bike_id and
            a.created_at between b.start and b.end")
```

Edit: As noted by @G. Grothendieck, we can set the timezone of the environment (with `Sys.setenv`) before reading in the data to match OP's timezone.

**Output:**

```
  bike_id          created_at         resolved_at id
1   28780 2019-05-03 08:29:18 2019-05-03 08:35:37  1
2   28780 2019-05-03 21:05:28 2019-05-03 21:07:28 NA
3   28780 2019-05-04 21:13:39 2019-05-04 21:15:40 NA
4   28780 2019-05-07 17:24:20 2019-05-07 17:26:39 NA
5   28780 2019-05-08 11:34:32 2019-05-08 12:16:44  3
6   28780 2019-05-08 23:38:39 2019-05-08 23:40:36 NA
```

**Data:** (OP's `dput` does work because of the pointer created from `data.table`)

```
Sys.setenv(TZ = "GMT")

records <- structure(list(bike_id = c(28780L, 28780L, 28780L, 28780L, 28780L, 
28780L), created_at = c("2019-05-03 08:29:18", "2019-05-03 21:05:28", 
"2019-05-04 21:13:39", "2019-05-07 17:24:20", "2019-05-08 11:34:32", 
"2019-05-08 23:38:39"), resolved_at = c("2019-05-03 08:35:37", 
"2019-05-03 21:07:28", "2019-05-04 21:15:40", "2019-05-07 17:26:39", 
"2019-05-08 12:16:44", "2019-05-08 23:40:36")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))

intervals <- structure(list(bike_id = c(28780L, 28780L, 28780L, 28780L, 28780L, 
28780L), start = c("2019-05-03 04:44:45", "2019-05-04 07:07:39", 
"2019-05-07 23:28:32", "2019-05-10 06:06:21", "2019-05-12 05:21:24", 
"2019-05-13 08:44:54"), end = c("2019-05-03 16:58:56", "2019-05-04 14:48:29", 
"2019-05-08 12:56:24", "2019-05-10 13:12:08", "2019-05-12 11:35:52", 
"2019-05-13 12:28:31"), id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Comment: I get the following error:
`Error in postgresqlNewConnection(drv, ...) : 
  RS-DBI driver: (could not connect postgres@localhost:5432 on dbname "test": could not connect to server: Connection refused
 Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
 TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Connection refused
 Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
 TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
)
Error in !dbPreExists : invalid argument type`

Comment: @the_darkside Do you have `RPostgreSQL` loaded before you run my code?

Comment: Yes, I unloaded it and then set `options(sqldf.driver = "SQLite")` which worked ! Thank you

Comment: You won't need to convert to character if you set your session to GMT: `Sys.setenv(TZ = "GMT")`.  Also suggest `a.created_at between  b.start and b.end`

Comment: @G.Grothendieck Good point. I've edited my answer with your suggestions.

Comment: I don't think SQL is perfect for that because it is slow. One might want to use R for faster in-memory processing rather than slow on-disk databases.

Answer (score 5):

We can use `data.table` nonequi join

```
library(data.table)
setDT(records)[intervals, on = .(bike_id, created_at >= start, created_at <= end)]
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative would be to join on `bike_id`and the date part of `created_at`, and then to remove IDs where `created_at` isn't in the interval `start`-`end`. This might solve the memory issue by breaking things up into separate steps:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(purrr)

intervals %>% 
    mutate(date = date(start)) %>% 
    right_join(mutate(records,
                      date = date(created_at)),
                      by = c("bike_id", "date")
              ) %>% 
    mutate(within = created_at %within% interval(start, end),
           within = replace_na(within, F),
           id = map2_dbl(id, within, ~ ifelse(.y, .x, NA))
           ) %>% 
    select(bike_id, id, created_at, resolved_at)
```

Which returns:

```r
# A tibble: 6 x 4
  bike_id    id created_at          resolved_at        
    <int> <dbl> <dttm>              <dttm>             
1   28780     1 2019-05-03 08:29:18 2019-05-03 08:35:37
2   28780    NA 2019-05-03 21:05:28 2019-05-03 21:07:28
3   28780    NA 2019-05-04 21:13:39 2019-05-04 21:15:40
4   28780    NA 2019-05-07 17:24:20 2019-05-07 17:26:39
5   28780    NA 2019-05-08 11:34:32 2019-05-08 12:16:44
6   28780    NA 2019-05-08 23:38:39 2019-05-08 23:40:36
```