# Check if list of dates fall between a list of date ranges then add associated values to new dataframe using R programming

Tags: r, for-loop, apply

I have a dataframe (df) with 4 columns: Start date, Stop date, Launch date, and NMBR (Usage amount - numerical value). I have another dataframe (usage) with two columns: time1 and usage. I am trying to check if each date in the time1 column in the usage dataframe falls between any of the start and end dates in the df dataframe. If it does fall in between the start and end date then capture the NMBR, store, and increment in the usage column in the usage dataframe. I am getting the error

> "Error in as.POSIXlt.character(x, tz, ...) : character string is not in a standard unambiguous format".

I am new to r programming but would like help figuring out how to resolve.

Here is sample code to help understand the logic I am going after:

```
time1 = seq(ISOdate(2018,09,17),ISOdate(2019,09,17), by = "hour")
usage = matrix(0,length(time1),1)

usage <- data.frame(time1,usage)

for (row in 1:nrow(df)) {
    starttime <- df[row, "STRT"]
    stoptime  <- df[row, "STOP"]
    launchtime <- df[row,"LNCHD"]
    ncpu <- df[row,"NMBR"]

    usage = apply(usage,1,add_ncpu)
    add_ncpu = function(x){ if(x > starttime && x < stoptime){x  = x + ncpu}}
}



df <- data91319_tier1pgms %>%
    select(STRT, STOP, LNCHD, NMBR)

> head(df)
        STRT       STOP      LNCHD NMBR
1 2018-09-13 2018-09-13 2018-09-13   48
2 2018-09-11 2018-09-11 2018-09-11  112
3 2018-09-11 2018-09-11 2018-09-11  112
4 2018-09-12 2018-09-12 2018-09-12   12
5 2018-09-12 2018-09-12 2018-09-12    4
6 2018-09-11 2018-09-11 2018-09-11  112
```

Comment: Can you show a small reproducible example  (`df`)

Comment: This https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56688598/left-joining-in-r-between-two-timestamps may help.

Comment: @akrun 

df <- data91319_tier1pgms %>%
    select(STRT, STOP, LNCHD, NMBR)

> head(df)
        STRT       STOP      LNCHD NMBR
1 2018-09-13 2018-09-13 2018-09-13   48
2 2018-09-11 2018-09-11 2018-09-11  112
3 2018-09-11 2018-09-11 2018-09-11  112
4 2018-09-12 2018-09-12 2018-09-12   12
5 2018-09-12 2018-09-12 2018-09-12    4
6 2018-09-11 2018-09-11 2018-09-11  112

Comment: @akrun Hi Akrun - I have updated the post w/ the df sample code and output.

Comment: any update on this one?